# Setting up Local Development Vagrant version backward compatibility, config.vm.customize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, environment, vagrant

I am trying to participate in the open source software catarse on github

I am going through this wiki to install catarse on my local machine

https://github.com/catarse/catarse/wiki/%5BEnglish%5D-How-to-install-and-run-Catarse

I posted the question on catarse google group but maybe someone here can enlighten me

Basically I installed vagrant 1.1 
installed librarian-chef gem to run the cookbooks
virtual box
Vagrant-vbguest

and when I go do vagrant up

here is the error

```
There were warnings and/or errors while loading your Vagrantfile.
Your Vagrantfile was written for an earlier version of Vagrant,
and while Vagrant does the best it can to remain backwards
compatible, there are some cases where things have changed
significantly enough to warrant a message. These messages are
shown below.

Warnings:
* `config.vm.customize` calls are VirtualBox-specific. If you're
using any other provider, you'll have to find provider-specific configuration
to translate to manually in your Vagrantfile.

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string.
```

I am having vagrant version incompatible error but I read from vagrant doc that 1.1x is backward compatible.

The vagrant file specified here

http://pastebin.com/5QW6QkEF

doesn't specify what version vagrant I have wrong. I have a feeling that I need to configure

config.vm.customize to my box

but I don't know how.

It will be great for someone to enlighten me instead of me digging through the doc which I am not quite familiar with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Vagrant on VirtualBox? If yes you can safely ignore hte warning because Vagrant tells you: the old config file (which it is indeed able to read and understand) is specific for VirtualBox only so you should pay attention when *not* using VirtualBox.

The second error is the worse: "Shell provisioner `args` must be a string." It was reported as a [bug](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1519) on Github and fixed so just upgrade your Vagrant or use the workaround mentioned in the issue.